# Getting the post terms 'wp_get_post_terms' per post when within the functions.php file

Tags: wp-query, functions, ajax, terms

I have used a form with an Ajax action to pull post information through on submit.

It works a charm. However, I have used categories to separate the work into categories. One of which is the brand.

Within the page template the script I use works, but when used in the functions.php file. It doesn't pull the required results through.

I think it may be something to do with when the query to the post is triggered or how the add_action is set up.

Can someone please help me pull through the name of the category found within the ID of 31? When used in the functions.php.

Here is what I have written:

```
if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

        echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece\" style=\"background-image: url(" . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ");\">";

            echo "<a href=\"" . get_the_permalink() . "\" class=\"box-link\"></a>";

            echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece-hover\">";

            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece-inner\">";

                echo "<h5 class=\"portfolio-tags\">" . the_tags('', ' / ', '') . "</h5>";
                echo "<h4 class=\"portfolio-title\">";
                echo the_title();
                echo "</h4>";

                echo "<h4 class=\"portfolio-company\">";

                    $brands = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category', array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'parent' => 31
                    ) );
                    foreach ( $brands as $brand ) {
                        echo $brand->name;
                    };

                echo "</h4>";

            echo "</div>";

        echo "</div>";

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Where literally everything works but the portfolio-company / $brands = wp_get_post_terms part.

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

So I'm assuming that there are actually posts in the category (ID: `31`), and based on the `wp_get_post_terms()` [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/):

> **`$post_id`**
>  (int) (Optional) The Post ID. **Does not default to the ID of the global `$post`.** Default 0.

It's likely that you're not passing the proper post ID to the `wp_get_post_terms()` function:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category', array(...) );
```

In that code, you have `$post` and yet, it's not defined anywhere in your code as in the question.

So if you're trying to get the ID of the current post in the WordPress Loop, where the post data is stored in the global `$post` variable, then you should first make the variable accessible in your function/code using `global $post;` like so:

```
global $post;
// here and after this line, you may now use $post->ID
if( $query->have_posts() ) :
...
endif;
```

Or you could also use [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) without having to do `global $post;`, particularly if all you wanted is to get the post ID:

```
wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', array(...) ); // here I don't use $post->ID
```

And it's probably worth mentioning that in standard templates such as `page.php`, the global `$post` variable is already "global-ed", hence you may access the `$post` anywhere in the template. (Well, not exactly "anywhere"; however, I'm not going to dig deeper into that in this answer..)

### Additional Notes

This is probably just a typo, but in the code in the question, you got a syntax error here:

```
foreach ( $brands as $brand ) {
  echo $brand->name;
}; // <- remove that ;
```

And you forgot the closing `endif;`..

Comment: Thats some top tips pal, thank you. I have swapped the '$post->ID' for 'get_the_ID()'. Now I have working code! Amazing c:

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! But would you please "accept" the answer, so that people know the question has an accepted solution? :)

Comment: And I hope you don't mind I edited the answer because it didn't seem properly worded... ;)

Comment: Not at all! I'm glad we found a quick fix, I knew it would be something silly!

Comment: Sally - why has this persons question been closed? I have written two answers and I won't get any credit. Killing me inside... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221950/want-to-achieve-same-animation-like-an-website/55222486?noredirect=1#comment97201393_55222486

Comment: Thanks a lot for accepting it, and about that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55221950/9217760).. you could see under the question the reason to why it was put on hold.. which is "*must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*".. But your answer there would remain and people could upvote it. ( Btw, we shouldn't discuss about it here... :) )